# Smooth function with two variables that depends only on the distance of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold and

$$f:M\times M \to \mathbb R$$

be a smooth function such that $f(x,y)$ only depends on the distance of $x,y$ in terms of the Riemannian metric $d$. I wonder if we can always find a **smooth** function $g:\mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R$ such that $g(d(x,y))=f(x,y)$.

I am inclined to believe that this might be false but I find it hard to produce a counterexample for the case even when $M=\mathbb R$. The distance function is smooth "almost everywhere" for $M=\mathbb R$. A solution for this particular case is also appreciated!

Comment: Taking $M = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $g(t) = t^2$ works, since $g(d(x,y)) = (x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2$ is a polynomial. I don't know what to do in the general case, but it's certainly possible sometimes.

Comment: @EricCanton Thanks, but I just noticed that I should change “find” to "always find". Do you have a counterexample then?